# Assigning one Mat object to another gives an error

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface, mat

I am receiving a Mat object from function parameter, when I assign this object to local Mat parameter, gives me this error:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:6.0/MRA58K/2256973:user/release-keys'
pid: 32563, tid: 333, name: Thread-12993  >>> com.adhamenaya <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Stack frame 10-22 09:44:20.605 14500 14500 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00232708  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/lib/arm/libGrafty.so (cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Ma
t const&)+244): Routine cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&) at D:/scryptech/ndk_project/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.
hpp:573
Stack frame 10-22 09:44:20.605 14500 14500 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0023b4ac  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/lib/arm/libGrafty.so (GraftySystem::setCurrentF
rame(cv::Mat&)+308): Routine GraftySystem::setCurrentFrame(cv::Mat&) at C:\Users\aenaya\git\GraftyAndroid\GraftyAndroid/jni/grafty-system-settings.cpp
:65
Stack frame 10-22 09:44:20.605 14500 14500 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 002b3374  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/lib/arm/libGrafty.so (Java_com_adhamenaya_Nativ
e_runGrafty+540): Routine Java_com_adhamenaya_Native_runGrafty at C:\Users\aenaya\git\GraftyAndroid\GraftyAndroid/jni/grafty-hr-main.cpp:97 (discrimin
ator 1)
Stack frame 10-22 09:44:20.605 14500 14500 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0036a491  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x29c000) (byte[] com
.adhamenaya.Native.runGrafty(java.lang.Long)+92)
Stack frame 10-22 09:44:20.605 14500 14500 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00369e3d  /data/app/com.adhamenaya-2/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x29c000) (void com.a
dhamenaya.MainActivity$2.run()+328)
Stack frame 10-22 09:44:20.606 14500 14500 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 729298d1  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1eb1000)
```

where: **grafty-hr-main.cpp:97**

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_adhamenaya_Native_runGrafty(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj,jlong frame) {

    cv::Mat& inFrame = *(cv::Mat*) frame;


line 97 >>>>    gsys.setCurrentFrame(inFrame);
```

and the **grafty-system-settings.cpp:65**

```
void GraftySystem::setCurrentFrame(cv::Mat& frame) {
    cv::Size2d imgRes;
    float resRatio;
line 65 >>>>>   this->nFrame = frame;

}
```

This `JNI` is called like this:

```
private Mat mGray;

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
        if (mRgba.empty())
            return null;
        else if (mRgba.channels() > 1)
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
        else
            mGray = mRgba;

        return mRgba;
    }
...
...
result = Native.runGrafty(mGray.getNativeObjAddr());
```

**Edit:**

**mat.inl.hpp:573**

```
    Mat& Mat::operator = (const Mat& m)
    {
        if( this != &m )
        {
            if( m.u )
                CV_XADD(&m.u->refcount, 1);
            release();
            flags = m.flags;
            if( dims <= 2 && m.dims <= 2 )
            {
                dims = m.dims;
                rows = m.rows;
                cols = m.cols;
line 573 >>>>   step[0] = m.step[0];
                step[1] = m.step[1];
            }
            else
                copySize(m);
            data = m.data;
            datastart = m.datastart;
            dataend = m.dataend;
            datalimit = m.datalimit;
            allocator = m.allocator;
            u = m.u;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Kindly, help me in figuring out what is the problem ?

Comment: Not easy to tell, but `fault addr 0x0` smells like a null pointer. This part sticks out `*(cv::Mat*) frame;` - what is `frame` and why do we need a complicated cast here?

Comment: `frame` is passed to `JNI fucntion` from java (OpenCV camera). Then this frame is passed to function `setCurrentFrame` to make some processing on the frame..

Comment: `Java_com_adhamenaya_Native_runGrafty(JNIEnv * env,jobject obj,jlong frame)` frame is the reference to mat from java side.

Comment: It's OpenCV 3.0.0, right?

Comment: My copy shows something irrelevant on line `mat.inl.hpp:573 `. What do you see there?

Comment: @AlexCohn please the update in the question

Comment: Oops, the same line that I see. I don't know how `m.step` or `this->step` can be **nullptr**, but apparently, this is what happens there. Well, your code does involve unnecessary Mat copying, but this should not crash, IMVHO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93051/discussion-between-adhamenaya-and-alex-cohn).

Comment: @AlexCohn Actually I spent 5 days in trying to figure out what is the problem. but all in vain :( .. Can you suggest any thing in this case ?